# Get curve values at a given altitude

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, physics

If I have the following data:

```
data={{-0.00315, 0.126753}, {0.158, 0.34738}, {0.318, 0.610518}, {0.482, 
  0.708348}, {0.65, 0.6813}, {0.819, 0.562896}, {0.99, 
  0.41172}, {1.16, 0.275113}, {1.329, 0.16488}, {1.498, 
  0.0798336}, {1.666, 
  0.00903414}, {1.834, -0.0418784}, {2.002, -0.0870378}, {2.17, \
-0.125302}, {2.337, -0.158785}, {2.505, -0.181961}, {2.672, \
-0.200542}, {2.839, -0.216578}, {3.006, -0.231223}, {3.173, \
-0.239746}, {3.34, -0.247273}, {3.506, -0.253446}, {3.673, \
-0.258429}, {3.84, -0.262291}, {4.007, -0.265895}, {4.174, \
-0.268853}, {4.34, -0.27127}, {4.507, -0.27241}, {4.674, -0.274048}, \
{4.84, -0.275682}, {5.007, -0.277236}, {5.174, -0.278333}, {5.341, \
-0.279446}, {5.507, -0.280439}, {5.674, -0.281374}, {5.841, \
-0.28189}, {6.007, -0.282508}, {6.174, -0.283111}, {6.341, \
-0.283684}, {6.507, -0.284136}, {6.674, -0.284641}, {6.841, \
-0.285097}, {7.007, -0.285508}, {7.174, -0.285923}, {7.341, \
-0.286333}, {7.507, -0.286723}, {7.674, -0.287128}, {7.841, \
-0.28745}, {8.008, -0.287768}, {8.174, -0.288012}, {8.341, \
-0.288185}, {8.508, -0.288388}, {8.674, -0.288586}, {8.841, \
-0.288765}, {9.008, -0.288923}, {9.174, -0.289066}, {9.341, \
-0.289241}, {9.508, -0.289455}, {9.674, -0.289681}, {9.841, \
-0.289853}, {10.008, -0.289974}, {10.174, -0.290014}, {10.341, \
-0.289988}, {10.508, -0.289898}, {10.674, -0.289901}, {10.841, \
-0.289859}, {11.008, -0.289781}, {11.174, -0.289699}, {11.341, \
-0.289642}, {11.508, -0.289568}, {11.674, -0.289438}, {11.841, \
-0.289345}, {12.008, -0.289218}, {12.174, -0.289121}, {12.341, \
-0.289008}, {12.508, -0.288971}, {12.674, -0.288876}, {12.841, \
-0.288826}, {13.008, -0.288822}, {13.174, -0.288812}, {13.341, \
-0.288805}, {13.508, -0.288748}, {13.674, -0.288629}, {13.841, \
-0.288436}, {14.008, -0.288274}, {14.174, -0.288134}, {14.341, \
-0.28802}, {14.508, -0.287779}, {14.674, -0.287551}, {14.841, \
-0.28736}, {15.008, -0.287181}, {15.175, -0.286937}, {15.341, \
-0.286592}, {15.508, -0.286185}, {15.674, -0.285752}, {15.841, \
-0.285263}, {16.008, -0.284903}, {16.174, -0.284575}, {16.341, \
-0.28426}, {16.508, -0.284071}, {16.674, -0.283819}, {16.841, \
-0.283513}, {17.008, -0.283166}, {17.174, -0.282799}, {17.341, \
-0.282432}, {17.508, -0.282055}, {17.674, -0.281696}, {17.841, \
-0.281354}, {18.008, -0.281035}, {18.174, -0.280757}, {18.341, \
-0.280478}, {18.508, -0.280334}, {18.674, -0.280169}, {18.841, \
-0.280018}, {19.008, -0.279858}, {19.174, -0.279541}, {19.341, \
-0.279208}, {19.508, -0.278857}, {19.674, -0.278511}, {19.841, \
-0.277801}, {20.008, -0.277262}, {20.174, -0.276875}, {20.341, \
-0.276549}, {20.508, -0.276254}, {20.674, -0.275957}, {20.841, \
-0.275636}, {21.008, -0.275297}, {21.174, -0.275031}, {21.341, \
-0.274609}, {21.508, -0.27409}, {21.674, -0.273611}, {21.841, \
-0.273017}, {22.008, -0.272631}, {22.174, -0.272325}, {22.341, \
-0.272017}, {22.508, -0.271829}, {22.674, -0.271543}, {22.841, \
-0.271195}, {23.008, -0.270794}, {23.174, -0.270298}, {23.341, \
-0.269889}, {23.508, -0.269427}, {23.674, -0.268928}, {23.841, \
-0.268469}, {24.008, -0.267981}, {24.174, -0.267485}, {24.341, \
-0.267031}, {24.508, -0.266577}, {24.674, -0.266117}, {24.841, \
-0.265664}, {25.008, -0.265204}, {25.174, -0.264693}, {25.341, \
-0.264208}, {25.508, -0.263781}, {25.674, -0.263336}, {25.841, \
-0.262832}, {26.008, -0.262378}, {26.174, -0.261943}, {26.341, \
-0.261538}, {26.508, -0.261139}, {26.674, -0.260697}, {26.841, \
-0.260294}, {27.008, -0.259955}, {27.174, -0.259616}, {27.341, \
-0.259274}, {27.508, -0.258875}, {27.674, -0.258428}, {27.841, \
-0.258035}, {28.008, -0.257551}, {28.174, -0.256993}, {28.341, \
-0.256446}, {28.508, -0.255803}, {28.674, -0.255216}, {28.841, \
-0.254585}, {29.008, -0.253943}, {29.174, -0.253247}, {29.341, \
-0.252542}, {29.507, -0.251793}, {29.674, -0.251058}, {29.841, \
-0.250282}, {30.007, -0.24952}, {30.174, -0.24874}, {30.341, \
-0.247909}, {30.507, -0.247148}, {30.674, -0.246381}, {30.841, \
-0.245575}, {31.007, -0.244719}, {31.174, -0.24374}, {31.341, \
-0.242809}, {31.507, -0.241985}, {31.674, -0.241181}, {31.841, \
-0.240141}, {32.007, -0.239135}, {32.174, -0.238192}, {32.34, \
-0.237251}, {32.507, -0.236159}, {32.674, -0.235149}, {32.84, \
-0.234189}, {33.007, -0.233218}, {33.174, -0.232171}, {33.34, \
-0.231172}, {33.507, -0.230185}, {33.674, -0.22918}, {33.84, \
-0.228132}, {34.007, -0.227082}, {34.174, -0.226049}, {34.34, \
-0.225023}, {34.507, -0.223832}, {34.673, -0.222559}, {34.84, \
-0.221244}, {35.007, -0.219934}, {35.173, -0.218317}, {35.34, \
-0.216785}, {35.507, -0.215324}, {35.673, -0.213929}, {35.84, \
-0.212302}, {36.006, -0.210644}, {36.173, -0.208982}, {36.34, \
-0.207308}, {36.506, -0.205411}, {36.673, -0.203602}, {36.84, \
-0.201773}, {37.006, -0.199953}, {37.173, -0.198106}, {37.339, \
-0.196219}, {37.506, -0.194192}, {37.673, -0.192115}, {37.839, \
-0.189914}, {38.006, -0.18776}, {38.172, -0.185668}, {38.339, \
-0.183607}, {38.506, -0.181263}, {38.672, -0.17896}, {38.839, \
-0.176679}, {39.005, -0.174385}, {39.172, -0.171894}, {39.339, \
-0.169328}, {39.505, -0.166651}, {39.672, -0.163939}, {39.838, \
-0.161041}, {40.005, -0.158169}, {40.172, -0.155214}, {40.338, \
-0.152182}, {40.505, -0.148979}, {40.671, -0.145736}, {40.838, \
-0.142339}, {41.004, -0.138837}, {41.171, -0.134978}, {41.337, \
-0.131147}, {41.504, -0.12719}, {41.671, -0.123083}, {41.837, \
-0.118575}, {42.004, -0.114119}, {42.17, -0.109542}, {42.337, \
-0.104877}, {42.503, -0.0996522}, {42.67, -0.0945852}, {42.836, \
-0.0891624}, {43.003, -0.083505}, {43.169, -0.076785}, {43.336, \
-0.0704892}, {43.502, -0.0641094}, {43.669, -0.0575858}, {43.835, \
-0.0505137}, {44.001, -0.0435692}, {44.168, -0.0365599}, {44.334, \
-0.0292208}, {44.501, -0.021045}, {44.667, -0.0131527}, {44.833, \
-0.00518114}, {45., 0.00288158}, {45.166, 0.011333}, {45.333, 
  0.0197519}, {45.499, 0.0282636}, {45.665, 0.0368329}, {45.832, 
  0.0457119}, {45.998, 0.0545137}, {46.165, 0.0633846}, {46.331, 
  0.0722946}, {46.497, 0.0813336}, {46.664, 0.090318}, {46.83, 
  0.0992748}, {46.996, 0.108215}, {47.163, 0.117015}, {47.329, 
  0.125778}, {47.496, 0.134474}, {47.662, 0.143154}, {47.828, 
  0.151453}, {47.995, 0.159776}, {48.161, 0.168047}, {48.328, 
  0.176035}, {48.494, 0.183261}, {48.66, 0.190688}, {48.827, 
  0.197972}, {48.993, 0.205079}, {49.16, 0.211915}, {49.326, 
  0.218641}, {49.493, 0.224641}, {49.659, 0.230096}, {49.826, 
  0.234929}, {49.992, 0.239776}, {50.159, 0.244378}, {50.325, 
  0.248743}, {50.492, 0.252269}, {50.658, 0.255722}, {50.825, 
  0.258829}, {50.991, 0.261665}, {51.158, 0.263764}, {51.325, 
  0.26555}, {51.491, 0.26677}, {51.658, 0.267373}, {51.824, 
  0.267384}, {51.991, 0.267375}, {52.158, 0.267326}, {52.324, 
  0.266765}, {52.491, 0.265855}, {52.658, 0.265103}, {52.825, 
  0.26389}, {52.991, 0.262271}, {53.158, 0.260472}, {53.325, 
  0.25842}, {53.491, 0.256185}, {53.658, 0.253946}, {53.825, 
  0.251351}, {53.992, 0.248946}, {54.158, 0.246508}, {54.325, 
  0.244065}, {54.492, 0.241578}, {54.659, 0.239058}, {54.825, 
  0.23647}, {54.992, 0.233869}, {55.159, 0.231235}, {55.326, 
  0.228711}, {55.492, 0.226229}, {55.659, 0.22376}, {55.826, 
  0.221422}, {55.993, 0.219029}, {56.159, 0.216697}, {56.326, 
  0.214469}, {56.493, 0.212241}, {56.66, 0.209987}, {56.826, 
  0.207697}, {56.993, 0.205387}, {57.16, 0.203096}, {57.326, 
  0.200839}, {57.493, 0.198632}, {57.66, 0.196401}, {57.827, 
  0.194282}, {57.993, 0.19223}, {58.16, 0.19021}, {58.327, 
  0.188157}, {58.494, 0.186269}, {58.66, 0.184274}, {58.827, 
  0.182289}, {58.994, 0.180325}, {59.161, 0.178318}, {59.327, 
  0.176348}, {59.494, 0.174424}, {59.661, 0.172544}, {59.827, 
  0.170756}, {59.994, 0.168949}, {60.161, 0.167176}, {60.328, 
  0.165421}, {60.494, 0.163828}, {60.661, 0.162229}, {60.828, 
  0.160689}, {60.994, 0.1592}, {61.161, 0.158029}, {61.328, 
  0.156791}, {61.495, 0.155587}, {61.661, 0.154434}, {61.828, 
  0.153685}, {61.995, 0.152843}, {62.161, 0.151995}, {62.328, 
  0.151172}, {62.495, 0.150676}, {62.661, 0.150183}, {62.828, 
  0.149729}, {62.995, 0.149264}, {63.161, 0.149044}, {63.328, 
  0.148768}, {63.495, 0.14846}, {63.661, 0.148177}, {63.828, 
  0.147968}, {63.995, 0.147832}, {64.161, 0.147751}, {64.328, 
  0.147681}, {64.495, 0.147871}, {64.661, 0.14798}, {64.828, 
  0.148045}, {64.995, 0.148127}, {65.161, 0.148333}, {65.328, 
  0.148519}, {65.495, 0.148746}, {65.661, 0.148993}, {65.828, 
  0.149293}, {65.995, 0.149581}, {66.161, 0.14984}, {66.328, 
  0.150074}, {66.495, 0.150317}, {66.661, 0.150594}, {66.828, 
  0.150893}, {66.995, 0.151145}, {67.161, 0.151349}, {67.328, 
  0.151596}, {67.495, 0.151879}, {67.661, 0.152171}, {67.828, 
  0.152417}, {67.995, 0.152683}, {68.161, 0.15298}, {68.328, 
  0.153264}, {68.494, 0.153519}, {68.661, 0.15379}, {68.828, 
  0.154074}, {68.994, 0.154343}, {69.161, 0.154639}, {69.328, 
  0.154867}, {69.494, 0.155066}, {69.661, 0.155256}, {69.828, 
  0.155428}, {69.994, 0.155633}, {70.161, 0.155835}, {70.328, 
  0.156048}, {70.494, 0.156208}, {70.661, 0.156371}, {70.828, 
  0.156583}, {70.994, 0.156855}, {71.161, 0.157074}, {71.328, 
  0.157241}, {71.494, 0.157373}, {71.661, 0.157471}, {71.828, 
  0.1576}, {71.994, 0.157742}, {72.161, 0.157854}, {72.328, 
  0.157965}, {72.494, 0.157954}, {72.661, 0.157978}, {72.828, 
  0.158011}, {72.994, 0.158083}, {73.161, 0.158084}, {73.328, 
  0.15812}, {73.494, 0.158182}, {73.661, 0.158249}, {73.827, 
  0.158411}, {73.994, 0.158559}, {74.161, 0.158732}, {74.327, 
  0.158946}, {74.494, 0.159179}, {74.661, 0.159352}, {74.827, 
  0.159518}, {74.994, 0.15972}, {75.161, 0.159878}, {75.327, 
  0.16}, {75.494, 0.16012}, {75.661, 0.160271}, {75.827, 
  0.160365}, {75.994, 0.160493}, {76.161, 0.160636}, {76.327, 
  0.160767}, {76.494, 0.161044}, {76.661, 0.161255}, {76.827, 
  0.161402}, {76.994, 0.161526}, {77.161, 0.161749}, {77.327, 
  0.161882}, {77.494, 0.161957}, {77.661, 0.162052}, {77.827, 
  0.162061}, {77.994, 0.162069}, {78.161, 0.162112}, {78.327, 
  0.162212}, {78.494, 0.162309}, {78.661, 0.162411}, {78.827, 
  0.162493}, {78.994, 0.162625}, {79.161, 0.16282}, {79.327, 
  0.163015}, {79.494, 0.163262}, {79.66, 0.163579}, {79.827, 
  0.163916}, {79.994, 0.164259}, {80.16, 0.164585}, {80.327, 
  0.164895}, {80.494, 0.165142}, {80.66, 0.165362}, {80.827, 
  0.165622}, {80.994, 0.165866}, {81.16, 0.16601}, {81.327, 
  0.166204}, {81.494, 0.166403}, {81.66, 0.166623}, {81.827, 
  0.166899}, {81.994, 0.167171}, {82.16, 0.167443}, {82.327, 
  0.16771}, {82.494, 0.167924}, {82.66, 0.16811}, {82.827, 
  0.168226}, {82.994, 0.168308}, {83.16, 0.168347}, {83.327, 
  0.168486}, {83.494, 0.168626}, {83.66, 0.168751}, {83.827, 
  0.169016}, {83.993, 0.169215}, {84.16, 0.16939}, {84.327, 
  0.16958}, {84.493, 0.169761}, {84.66, 0.169925}, {84.827, 
  0.170097}, {84.993, 0.17027}, {85.16, 0.170453}, {85.327, 
  0.170647}, {85.493, 0.170833}, {85.66, 0.171079}, {85.827, 
  0.171308}, {85.993, 0.171482}, {86.16, 0.171641}, {86.327, 
  0.171863}, {86.493, 0.171949}, {86.66, 0.172118}, {86.827, 
  0.172321}, {86.993, 0.172513}, {87.16, 0.172724}, {87.327, 
  0.172895}, {87.493, 0.17308}, {87.66, 0.173278}, {87.827, 
  0.173467}, {87.993, 0.173731}, {88.16, 0.174029}, {88.326, 
  0.174274}, {88.493, 0.174671}, {88.66, 0.175004}, {88.826, 
  0.175321}, {88.993, 0.175669}, {89.16, 0.175955}, {89.326, 
  0.176202}, {89.493, 0.176432}, {89.66, 0.176686}, {89.826, 
  0.176854}, {89.993, 0.177096}, {90.16, 0.177341}, {90.326, 
  0.177566}, {90.493, 0.177875}, {90.66, 0.178146}, {90.826, 
  0.178371}, {90.993, 0.178553}, {91.16, 0.178652}, {91.326, 
  0.178772}, {91.493, 0.178895}, {91.66, 0.179004}, {91.826, 
  0.179097}, {91.993, 0.179259}, {92.16, 0.179472}, {92.326, 
  0.179722}, {92.493, 0.180107}, {92.659, 0.180471}, {92.826, 
  0.180821}, {92.993, 0.18114}, {93.159, 0.181528}, {93.326, 
  0.181818}, {93.493, 0.182092}, {93.659, 0.182398}, {93.826, 
  0.182523}, {93.993, 0.182656}, {94.159, 0.182842}, {94.326, 
  0.183071}, {94.493, 0.183302}, {94.659, 0.183563}, {94.826, 
  0.183825}, {94.993, 0.184069}, {95.159, 0.184417}, {95.326, 
  0.184631}, {95.493, 0.184816}, {95.659, 0.185008}, {95.826, 
  0.185064}, {95.993, 0.185173}, {96.159, 0.185291}, {96.326, 
  0.185458}, {96.492, 0.18562}, {96.659, 0.185752}, {96.826, 
  0.185963}, {96.992, 0.186226}, {97.159, 0.186486}, {97.326, 
  0.186771}, {97.492, 0.187079}, {97.659, 0.187382}, {97.826, 
  0.187623}, {97.992, 0.187864}, {98.159, 0.188131}, {98.326, 
  0.188344}, {98.492, 0.188504}, {98.659, 0.188669}, {98.826, 
  0.188812}, {98.992, 0.188936}, {99.159, 0.18909}, {99.326, 
  0.18928}, {99.492, 0.189456}, {99.659, 0.189623}, {99.826, 
  0.189791}}
```

which plotted like `ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{20, 80}, All}]` gives:

[image]

**Question:**

How can I calculate `DT` like in this Figure?:

[image]

**Steps to calculate `DT`:**

1. Get the extrapolated lines of the two base lines like this:

   `datglass = Select[data, 20 <= #[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShUXz.png)] <= 33 &];
   datliq = Select[datTCpc, 65 <= #[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShUXz.png)] <= 80 &];
   mod1 = LinearModelFit[datglass2, x, x];
   mod2 = LinearModelFit[datliq2, x, x];

   Show[

   ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{20, 80}, All}],

   Plot[mod1[x], {x, 20, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed}],

   Plot[mod2[x], {x, 20, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed}]

   ]`

which gives:

[image]

2. Get the change of the extrapolated lines at one temperature (for example 45) like this:

`mod2[45] - mod1[45] (*0.340854*)`

**Please notice that this change is performed at a single x-value. Depending on the x-value choosen (here 45) the 16% change or 84% can be different. If I choose this to be x=30, then the total change would be slightly smaller and therefor 16% and 84% will be reach at different points than at x=45 as an example**

3. Get the value where the change calculated in step 2 is approximately 16% (starting from down to up) and also where it is 84% and get the x-value of the curve at those points. Lets call the point at 16% x1 and the one at 84% x2. **This step I dont know how to do it**
4. Calculate `DT` by simply subtracting the x values at 84% and 16% simply by `x2-x1`. In the reference figure `DT`is 5 as x1 was 40 and x2 was 45.

**PLEASE NOTICE THAT I AM NOT ASKING FOR HOW TO DRAW THE PLOT BUT TO GET THE `DT` VALUE. IT WOULD BE A PLUS THE PLOT AND THE VALUE. IN THIS CASE `DT` IS NOT NECCESARY 5 AS THIS IS ANOTHER TYPE OF DATA**

**UPDATA WITH ANOTHER DATA**

I am trying to use the same code developed by @Daniel Huber with this data:

```
data1={{-0.001538, 2.26641}, {0.163, 2.70654}, {0.328, 2.97845}, {0.495, 
  2.80285}, {0.665, 2.29012}, {0.837, 1.35502}, {1.009, 
  0.477173}, {1.18, -0.256822}, {1.35, -0.878713}, {1.519, -1.27913}, \
{1.688, -1.60982}, {1.856, -1.8833}, {2.024, -2.12398}, {2.192, \
-2.29115}, {2.359, -2.4347}, {2.527, -2.54921}, {2.694, -2.64513}, \
{2.861, -2.70857}, {3.028, -2.76646}, {3.195, -2.81171}, {3.362, \
-2.85255}, {3.529, -2.8834}, {3.696, -2.90407}, {3.862, -2.92046}, \
{4.029, -2.93558}, {4.196, -2.94825}, {4.363, -2.96032}, {4.53, \
-2.97217}, {4.696, -2.9837}, {4.863, -2.99274}, {5.03, -3.00218}, \
{5.197, -3.0115}, {5.363, -3.02062}, {5.53, -3.02815}, {5.697, \
-3.03603}, {5.864, -3.04375}, {6.03, -3.0516}, {6.197, -3.05826}, \
{6.364, -3.06483}, {6.531, -3.07113}, {6.697, -3.07755}, {6.864, \
-3.08303}, {7.031, -3.08886}, {7.197, -3.09423}, {7.364, -3.09916}, \
{7.531, -3.1043}, {7.698, -3.1094}, {7.864, -3.11439}, {8.031, \
-3.11904}, {8.198, -3.1233}, {8.365, -3.12774}, {8.531, -3.13246}, \
{8.698, -3.13688}, {8.865, -3.14108}, {9.031, -3.14528}, {9.198, \
-3.14939}, {9.365, -3.1533}, {9.532, -3.15764}, {9.698, -3.16169}, \
{9.865, -3.16552}, {10.032, -3.16904}, {10.199, -3.17313}, {10.365, \
-3.17728}, {10.532, -3.18108}, {10.699, -3.18471}, {10.865, \
-3.18847}, {11.032, -3.19205}, {11.199, -3.19563}, {11.366, \
-3.19922}, {11.532, -3.20244}, {11.699, -3.20571}, {11.866, \
-3.20887}, {12.032, -3.21203}, {12.199, -3.21519}, {12.366, \
-3.21798}, {12.533, -3.22049}, {12.699, -3.22305}, {12.866, \
-3.22566}, {13.033, -3.22817}, {13.199, -3.23038}, {13.366, \
-3.23265}, {13.533, -3.23521}, {13.7, -3.23757}, {13.866, -3.23994}, \
{14.033, -3.24213}, {14.2, -3.24431}, {14.366, -3.24665}, {14.533, \
-3.249}, {14.7, -3.25138}, {14.867, -3.2536}, {15.033, -3.25595}, \
{15.2, -3.25822}, {15.367, -3.26053}, {15.533, -3.26267}, {15.7, \
-3.26504}, {15.867, -3.26735}, {16.034, -3.26972}, {16.2, -3.27189}, \
{16.367, -3.2743}, {16.534, -3.27689}, {16.7, -3.27947}, {16.867, \
-3.28199}, {17.034, -3.28426}, {17.201, -3.28623}, {17.367, \
-3.28811}, {17.534, -3.28959}, {17.701, -3.29127}, {17.867, \
-3.29278}, {18.034, -3.2943}, {18.201, -3.29545}, {18.368, -3.2967}, \
{18.534, -3.29812}, {18.701, -3.2995}, {18.868, -3.3007}, {19.034, \
-3.30211}, {19.201, -3.30348}, {19.368, -3.30471}, {19.535, \
-3.30603}, {19.701, -3.30718}, {19.868, -3.30833}, {20.035, \
-3.30956}, {20.201, -3.31049}, {20.368, -3.31168}, {20.535, \
-3.31328}, {20.701, -3.31484}, {20.868, -3.31616}, {21.035, \
-3.31781}, {21.202, -3.31942}, {21.368, -3.32071}, {21.535, \
-3.32215}, {21.702, -3.32349}, {21.868, -3.32466}, {22.035, \
-3.32584}, {22.202, -3.32742}, {22.369, -3.3288}, {22.535, -3.33023}, \
{22.702, -3.33186}, {22.869, -3.33367}, {23.035, -3.33526}, {23.202, \
-3.33679}, {23.369, -3.33836}, {23.536, -3.339}, {23.702, -3.33991}, \
{23.869, -3.34088}, {24.036, -3.34209}, {24.202, -3.34272}, {24.369, \
-3.34368}, {24.536, -3.34489}, {24.703, -3.34625}, {24.869, \
-3.34804}, {25.036, -3.3494}, {25.203, -3.35063}, {25.369, -3.35232}, \
{25.536, -3.35339}, {25.703, -3.35458}, {25.869, -3.35593}, {26.036, \
-3.35718}, {26.203, -3.35729}, {26.37, -3.35783}, {26.536, -3.3587}, \
{26.703, -3.35954}, {26.87, -3.35995}, {27.036, -3.36046}, {27.203, \
-3.3609}, {27.37, -3.36126}, {27.537, -3.36167}, {27.703, -3.36184}, \
{27.87, -3.3621}, {28.037, -3.36258}, {28.203, -3.36325}, {28.37, \
-3.36399}, {28.537, -3.36457}, {28.703, -3.36515}, {28.87, -3.36614}, \
{29.037, -3.36694}, {29.204, -3.36787}, {29.37, -3.36887}, {29.537, \
-3.36937}, {29.704, -3.37021}, {29.87, -3.3711}, {30.037, -3.37182}, \
{30.204, -3.37223}, {30.37, -3.37274}, {30.537, -3.37345}, {30.704, \
-3.3742}, {30.871, -3.37456}, {31.037, -3.37516}, {31.204, -3.37571}, \
{31.371, -3.37625}, {31.537, -3.37699}, {31.704, -3.37766}, {31.871, \
-3.37825}, {32.038, -3.37866}, {32.204, -3.37932}, {32.371, \
-3.37987}, {32.538, -3.38029}, {32.704, -3.38055}, {32.871, \
-3.38092}, {33.038, -3.38099}, {33.204, -3.38103}, {33.371, -3.3811}, \
{33.538, -3.38113}, {33.705, -3.38101}, {33.871, -3.38074}, {34.038, \
-3.38059}, {34.205, -3.38085}, {34.371, -3.38078}, {34.538, \
-3.38033}, {34.705, -3.37953}, {34.871, -3.37892}, {35.038, \
-3.37818}, {35.205, -3.37749}, {35.372, -3.37687}, {35.538, \
-3.37601}, {35.705, -3.37528}, {35.872, -3.37484}, {36.038, \
-3.37447}, {36.205, -3.37399}, {36.372, -3.37346}, {36.538, \
-3.37283}, {36.705, -3.37201}, {36.872, -3.37123}, {37.038, \
-3.37041}, {37.205, -3.36921}, {37.372, -3.3677}, {37.539, -3.36629}, \
{37.705, -3.3648}, {37.872, -3.36307}, {38.039, -3.3611}, {38.205, \
-3.35875}, {38.372, -3.35683}, {38.539, -3.35479}, {38.705, \
-3.35248}, {38.872, -3.3493}, {39.039, -3.3461}, {39.205, -3.34291}, \
{39.372, -3.3396}, {39.539, -3.33475}, {39.705, -3.33046}, {39.872, \
-3.32603}, {40.039, -3.32139}, {40.205, -3.31585}, {40.372, \
-3.31055}, {40.539, -3.30487}, {40.705, -3.2992}, {40.872, -3.29307}, \
{41.039, -3.28689}, {41.205, -3.28041}, {41.372, -3.27368}, {41.539, \
-3.26604}, {41.705, -3.25817}, {41.872, -3.2497}, {42.039, -3.23927}, \
{42.205, -3.2273}, {42.372, -3.2156}, {42.538, -3.20316}, {42.705, \
-3.19005}, {42.872, -3.17445}, {43.038, -3.15944}, {43.205, \
-3.14379}, {43.371, -3.12596}, {43.538, -3.10652}, {43.704, \
-3.08829}, {43.871, -3.06856}, {44.038, -3.04632}, {44.204, \
-3.01981}, {44.37, -2.99224}, {44.537, -2.96199}, {44.703, -2.92876}, \
{44.87, -2.89357}, {45.036, -2.85849}, {45.203, -2.82048}, {45.369, \
-2.78032}, {45.535, -2.73557}, {45.702, -2.69131}, {45.868, \
-2.64817}, {46.035, -2.60535}, {46.201, -2.56072}, {46.367, \
-2.51781}, {46.534, -2.4778}, {46.7, -2.43909}, {46.867, -2.41276}, \
{47.033, -2.39244}, {47.2, -2.38113}, {47.366, -2.37666}, {47.533, \
-2.39127}, {47.7, -2.41467}, {47.867, -2.44979}, {48.034, -2.49259}, \
{48.201, -2.55015}, {48.368, -2.61479}, {48.536, -2.67798}, {48.703, \
-2.74132}, {48.87, -2.80162}, {49.037, -2.85702}, {49.204, -2.90587}, \
{49.371, -2.94993}, {49.538, -2.9812}, {49.705, -3.00676}, {49.872, \
-3.02562}, {50.039, -3.04274}, {50.205, -3.05399}, {50.372, \
-3.06421}, {50.539, -3.07176}, {50.706, -3.07712}, {50.872, \
-3.08042}, {51.039, -3.08486}, {51.206, -3.08872}, {51.373, \
-3.09215}, {51.539, -3.0944}, {51.706, -3.09713}, {51.873, -3.09956}, \
{52.039, -3.1018}, {52.206, -3.10331}, {52.373, -3.10512}, {52.54, \
-3.10694}, {52.706, -3.10889}, {52.873, -3.11015}, {53.04, -3.11155}, \
{53.206, -3.11276}, {53.373, -3.11392}, {53.54, -3.11483}, {53.707, \
-3.11594}, {53.873, -3.11723}, {54.04, -3.1187}, {54.207, -3.11987}, \
{54.373, -3.1208}, {54.54, -3.12182}, {54.707, -3.12322}, {54.874, \
-3.12389}, {55.04, -3.1249}, {55.207, -3.12583}, {55.374, -3.12675}, \
{55.54, -3.12768}, {55.707, -3.12841}, {55.874, -3.12894}, {56.04, \
-3.12974}, {56.207, -3.13029}, {56.374, -3.13117}, {56.541, \
-3.13199}, {56.707, -3.13253}, {56.874, -3.13346}, {57.041, \
-3.13419}, {57.207, -3.1349}, {57.374, -3.13577}, {57.541, -3.13673}, \
{57.707, -3.13775}, {57.874, -3.13874}, {58.041, -3.13986}, {58.208, \
-3.14108}, {58.374, -3.14227}, {58.541, -3.14371}, {58.708, \
-3.14541}, {58.874, -3.14667}, {59.041, -3.14806}, {59.208, \
-3.14936}, {59.375, -3.15035}, {59.541, -3.15093}, {59.708, \
-3.15153}, {59.875, -3.15204}, {60.041, -3.15259}, {60.208, \
-3.15286}, {60.375, -3.15331}, {60.542, -3.15382}, {60.708, \
-3.15441}, {60.875, -3.15526}, {61.042, -3.15584}, {61.208, \
-3.15649}, {61.375, -3.15735}, {61.542, -3.15794}, {61.708, \
-3.15853}, {61.875, -3.15903}, {62.042, -3.15954}, {62.209, \
-3.16029}, {62.375, -3.16111}, {62.542, -3.16198}, {62.709, \
-3.16293}, {62.875, -3.16414}, {63.042, -3.16488}, {63.209, \
-3.16523}, {63.376, -3.16544}, {63.542, -3.16512}, {63.709, \
-3.16478}, {63.876, -3.16447}, {64.042, -3.1643}, {64.209, -3.16428}, \
{64.376, -3.16453}, {64.542, -3.16472}, {64.709, -3.16491}, {64.876, \
-3.16592}, {65.043, -3.16649}, {65.209, -3.1669}, {65.376, -3.16724}, \
{65.543, -3.16794}, {65.709, -3.16872}, {65.876, -3.16947}, {66.043, \
-3.17045}, {66.209, -3.17175}, {66.376, -3.17286}, {66.543, \
-3.17388}, {66.71, -3.17486}, {66.876, -3.1752}, {67.043, -3.17552}, \
{67.21, -3.17595}, {67.376, -3.17627}, {67.543, -3.17659}, {67.71, \
-3.17722}, {67.877, -3.17765}, {68.043, -3.17803}, {68.21, -3.1792}, \
{68.377, -3.17991}, {68.543, -3.18039}, {68.71, -3.18084}, {68.877, \
-3.18093}, {69.043, -3.18112}, {69.21, -3.18162}, {69.377, -3.18217}, \
{69.544, -3.18261}, {69.71, -3.18302}, {69.877, -3.18345}, {70.044, \
-3.18395}, {70.21, -3.18487}, {70.377, -3.18543}, {70.544, -3.186}, \
{70.711, -3.18667}, {70.877, -3.18754}, {71.044, -3.18849}, {71.211, \
-3.18952}, {71.377, -3.19067}, {71.544, -3.19142}, {71.711, \
-3.19204}, {71.877, -3.19248}, {72.044, -3.19301}, {72.211, \
-3.19295}, {72.378, -3.19334}, {72.544, -3.19394}, {72.711, \
-3.19464}, {72.878, -3.19587}, {73.044, -3.19667}, {73.211, \
-3.19722}, {73.378, -3.19759}, {73.545, -3.198}, {73.711, -3.19873}, \
{73.878, -3.1996}, {74.045, -3.20035}, {74.211, -3.20105}, {74.378, \
-3.2019}, {74.545, -3.20264}, {74.711, -3.20322}, {74.878, -3.20365}, \
{75.045, -3.20413}, {75.212, -3.20473}, {75.378, -3.20529}, {75.545, \
-3.20568}, {75.712, -3.20605}, {75.878, -3.20645}, {76.045, \
-3.20676}, {76.212, -3.20722}, {76.378, -3.20783}, {76.545, \
-3.20856}, {76.712, -3.20912}, {76.879, -3.20979}, {77.045, \
-3.21056}, {77.212, -3.21135}, {77.379, -3.21183}, {77.545, \
-3.21243}, {77.712, -3.21325}, {77.879, -3.21396}, {78.046, \
-3.21456}, {78.212, -3.21531}, {78.379, -3.216}, {78.546, -3.21655}, \
{78.712, -3.21719}, {78.879, -3.21792}, {79.046, -3.21871}, {79.212, \
-3.21949}, {79.379, -3.22028}, {79.546, -3.22158}, {79.713, \
-3.22287}, {79.879, -3.2241}, {80.046, -3.22514}, {80.213, -3.22613}, \
{80.379, -3.22681}, {80.546, -3.22724}, {80.713, -3.22747}, {80.88, \
-3.22699}, {81.046, -3.22707}, {81.213, -3.22742}, {81.38, -3.2278}, \
{81.546, -3.22833}, {81.713, -3.22886}, {81.88, -3.22959}, {82.046, \
-3.23035}, {82.213, -3.231}, {82.38, -3.23159}, {82.547, -3.23249}, \
{82.713, -3.23358}, {82.88, -3.23417}, {83.047, -3.23486}, {83.213, \
-3.23547}, {83.38, -3.23607}, {83.547, -3.23639}, {83.714, -3.23688}, \
{83.88, -3.23748}, {84.047, -3.23806}, {84.214, -3.23832}, {84.38, \
-3.23879}, {84.547, -3.23916}, {84.714, -3.23936}, {84.88, -3.23948}, \
{85.047, -3.23981}, {85.214, -3.24034}, {85.381, -3.24109}, {85.547, \
-3.24182}, {85.714, -3.24256}, {85.881, -3.24324}, {86.047, \
-3.24377}, {86.214, -3.2442}, {86.381, -3.24476}, {86.548, -3.24538}, \
{86.714, -3.2459}, {86.881, -3.24629}, {87.048, -3.24686}, {87.214, \
-3.24733}, {87.381, -3.24774}, {87.548, -3.24829}, {87.714, \
-3.24898}, {87.881, -3.24949}, {88.048, -3.24984}, {88.215, \
-3.25029}, {88.381, -3.25082}, {88.548, -3.25122}, {88.715, \
-3.25177}, {88.881, -3.25247}, {89.048, -3.25315}, {89.215, \
-3.25372}, {89.381, -3.25427}, {89.548, -3.25475}, {89.715, \
-3.25498}, {89.882, -3.25505}}
```

But when I use the same (except the limits) it doesn't seem to quite work exact, as I get a `DT` which visually seems to be lower and the plot also doesn't quite get the values on the curve. What am I doing wrong here?. The code is as follows:

```
n11 = 20; n12 = 35; (*Glass line limits*)
n21 = 50; n22 = 60; (*Liquid line limits*)
n31 = n11; n32 = n21; (*Region in between*)
tan1[x_] = Fit[Select[data1, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n12 &], {1, x}, x];
tan2[x_] = Fit[Select[data1, n21 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &], {1, x}, x];
pol = Fit[Select[data1, n31 <= #[[1]] <= n32 &], {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];
infl = x /. Solve[D[pol, {x, 2}] == 0, x][[1]];
ys = {tan1[infl], tan2[infl]};
{y16, y84} = ys[[1]] + {0.16, 0.84} (ys[[2]] - ys[[1]]);
{x16, x84} = (x /. 
     Solve[{pol == #, n31 < x < n32}, x][[1]]) & /@ {y16, y84}
DT = x84 - x16 (*5.6063*)
xm = (x16 + x84)/2;
ym = (y16 + y84)/2;

Show[ListLinePlot[Select[data1, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &]], 
 Graphics[{Line[{{{n11, tan1[n11]}, {n32, tan1[n32]}}, {{n31, 
       tan2[n31]}, {n22, tan2[n22]}}}], 
   Line[{{xm, tan1[xm]}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}], PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[Transpose[{{x16, x84}, {y16, y84}}]], {Dashed, 
    Line[{{x16, y16}, {x16, y16 + 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}], 
    Line[{{x84, y84}, {x84, y84 - 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}]}, 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, y16}, {x16, y16}}], Text["16%", {x16 - 13, y16}],
    Arrow[{{x84 + 10, y84}, {x84, y84}}], 
   Text["84%", {x84 + 13, y84}], 
   Arrow[{{xm + 10, tan1[xm] - 0.05}, {xm, tan1[xm]}}], 
   Text["1.19%", {xm + 14, tan1[xm] - 0.05}], 
   Arrow[{{xm - 10, tan2[xm] + 0.05}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}], 
   Text["1.19%", {xm - 14, tan2[xm] + 0.05}], 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, ym}, {x16, ym}}], 
   Text[NumberForm[x84 - x16, 3], {x84 + 7, ym - 0.03}], 
   Arrow[{{x84 + 10, ym}, {x84, ym}}]}]]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Can you clean up the data you have posted? In the beginning of the list there are many `\` characters that should not be present. It will make it easier for other users (including myself!) to submit answers. Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian thank you! I will !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version where you specify the the x position, at which the height difference between the two base lines is measured:

```
xm = 42; (*measure position*)
n11 = 25; n12 = 35; n21 = 60; n22 = 80; n31 = 30; n32 = 50;

tan1[x_] = Fit[Select[data1, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n12 &], {1, x}, x];
tan2[x_] = Fit[Select[data1, n21 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &], {1, x}, x];
intpol = Interpolation[Select[data1, n31 <= #[[1]] <= n32 &]];

ys = {tan1[xm], tan2[xm]};
{y16, y84} = ys[[1]] + {0.16, 0.84} (ys[[2]] - ys[[1]]);
{x16, x84} = 
  x /. {FindRoot[intpol[x] == y16, {x, 35, 40}], 
    FindRoot[intpol[x] == y84, {x, 40, 45}]};
ym = (y16 + y84)/2;

Show[ListLinePlot[Select[data1, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &], 
  PlotRange -> {-3.5, -2.5}], 
 Graphics[{Line[{{{n11, tan1[n11]}, {n21, tan1[n21]}}, {{n12, 
       tan2[n12]}, {n22, tan2[n22]}}}], 
   Line[{{xm, tan1[xm]}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}], PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[Transpose[{{x16, x84}, {y16, y84}}]], {Dashed, 
    Line[{{x16, y16}, {x16, y16 + 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}], 
    Line[{{x84, y84}, {x84, y84 - 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}]}, 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, y16}, {x16, y16}}], 
   Text["16%", {x16 - 5, y16 + 0.02}], 
   Arrow[{{x84 + 10, y84}, {x84, y84}}],
   Text["84%", {x84 + 5, y84 - 0.03}], 
   Arrow[{{xm + 10, tan1[xm]}, {xm, tan1[xm]}}], 
   Text[NumberForm[ys[[1]], 3], {xm + 6, tan1[xm] + 0.02}], 
   Arrow[{{xm - 10, tan2[xm]}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}]
   , Text[NumberForm[ys[[2]], 3], {xm - 6, tan2[xm] - 0.04}], 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, ym}, {x16, ym}}]
   , Text[NumberForm[x84 - x16, 3], {x84 + 7, ym - 0.03}], 
   Arrow[{{x84 + 10, ym}, {x84, ym}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much! This version is absolutely fantastic and more robust!!!

Answer (score 3):

MMA make it easy to draw complicated graphics like::

```
n11 = 10; n12 = 25; n21 = 62; n22 = 80; n31 = 30; n32 = 52;
tan1[x_] = Fit[Select[data, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n12 &], {1, x}, x];
tan2[x_] = Fit[Select[data, n21 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &], {1, x}, x];
pol = Fit[Select[data, n31 <= #[[1]] <= n32 &], {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x];
infl = x /. Solve[D[pol, {x, 2}] == 0, x][[1]];
ys = {tan1[infl], tan2[infl]};
{y16, y84} = ys[[1]] + {0.16, 0.84} (ys[[2]] - ys[[1]]);
{x16, x84} = (x /. 
     Solve[{pol == #, n31 < x < n32}, x][[1]]) & /@ {y16, y84}
xm = (x16 + x84)/2;
ym = (y16 + y84)/2;

Show[ListLinePlot[Select[data, n11 <= #[[1]] <= n22 &]], 
 Graphics[{Line[{{{n11, tan1[n11]}, {n32, tan1[n32]}}, {{n31, 
       tan2[n31]}, {n22, tan2[n22]}}}], 
   Line[{{xm, tan1[xm]}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}], PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[Transpose[{{x16, x84}, {y16, y84}}]], {Dashed, 
    Line[{{x16, y16}, {x16, y16 + 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}], 
    Line[{{x84, y84}, {x84, y84 - 0.6 (y84 - y16)}}]}, 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, y16}, {x16, y16}}], Text["16%", {x16 - 13, y16}],
    Arrow[{{x84 + 10, y84}, {x84, y84}}], 
   Text["84%", {x84 + 13, y84}], 
   Arrow[{{xm + 10, tan1[xm] - 0.05}, {xm, tan1[xm]}}], 
   Text["1.19%", {xm + 14, tan1[xm] - 0.05}], 
   Arrow[{{xm - 10, tan2[xm] + 0.05}, {xm, tan2[xm]}}], 
   Text["1.19%", {xm - 14, tan2[xm] + 0.05}], 
   Arrow[{{x16 - 10, ym}, {x16, ym}}], 
   Text[NumberForm[x84 - x16, 3], {x84 + 7, ym - 0.03}], 
   Arrow[{{x84 + 10, ym}, {x84, ym}}]}]
 
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Daniel thank you ! Although I would also like the graphic, I am more interested in the value of DT for this data (which may not be 5)

Comment: It is the difference of  x84 and x16.

Comment: Daniel thanks! The problem I think is that when I run the code as it I get: `Set::shape: Lists {x16,x84} and y1684 are not the same shape.` and `Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {x1684,y1684} cannot be transposed.`. `x16` and `x84` seem to have a problem.

Comment: I apologize, there was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: I also included  the value of dT  in the plot.

Comment: Daniel! Can you see the update? I am trying to use a different set of data but it is not quite working as it should. What am I doing wrong? Is it the limits that I selected wrong?

Comment: Daniel, I think the problem of the code (as shown in the updated data) might have to do with the selection of `n31` and `n32`. The subraction change of the lines should be done at a single point (in the updated example would be like around 40).

Comment: Your new `data1` has a problem. The base line on the right side  cuts the curve before the inflexion point.  By this the whole definition of dT fails.

Comment: Daniel how could I accomodate your code to this new data? It surely can be done even with this data, right? I think it is important to take the region of `n31` and `n32` just as a single value like 40 or 42 for this new data. Actually take it at 40

Comment: As I understand it, you measure the height at the position of the inflexion point. Makes dT still sense, if the right base line cuts the curve to the left of the the inflexion point?

Comment: Daniel, I measure the change in the height based on a single temperature, which is defined as the Tg, as is defined by me according to a calculation. Given this single point where the change is measure, the 16% can cut the curve the right or to the left of the change line (in the example is to the left but it could very well be to the right if that Tg is low enough). Then once we have the change line, we simply look for the value of 16% and 84% and see where it goes into the actual curve and then calculate the difference. I hope that makes more sense now and thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the y values of points on the curve and are looking for the belonging x values, the problem is much simpler.
Say we have `data1` and want to know what x values belongs to the know y value. As an example assume we have y=-3.1. Then, from a plot of the function, guess an x value: x1 to the left and one: x2 to the right of the given y. Then use e.g FindRoot:

```
x1 = 40; x2 = 45;
intpol = Interpolation[data1];
x0 = x /. FindRoot[intpol[x] == -3.1, {x, 40, 45}]
Plot[intpol[x], {x, 1, 80}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x0, intpol[x0]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, daniel, no. I am still looking for `DT` as in the reference Figure. The only thing I know is at what temperature (x value) I want to calculate the change between the upper extrapolated line and the bottom extrapolated line (this value is 40 for `data1`). I still need to calculate based on this "change line" when it is about 16% or 84% of its value where in the x-axis it will be in the curve (remember the "change line" is not in the actual curve). the x-values that I am looking for can be to the right or to the left of this "change line".

Comment: To be more clear, if I calculate the "change line" (difference between upper and bottom extrapolated lines) at say 30 when compared with 40, they will give different results at 16% and 84% in the actual curve. When I am at x=30 the change will be lower than the change if I am at x=40 and therefore the `DT` value will be different. So, the only thing I know is a reference x value where I want to get that change line. I hope that is more clear now

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You specify an x value: x0. Then you get the y values y10, y20 from the two extrapolated lines. Then from this you get the 16 and  84 percent values: y16 and y64. And from this the belonging x values of the curve x16 and x64.  Can you describe where you have a  problem?

Comment: The problem I have is that in your terms I don't know how to get `x16` and `x84` because they need to be in the extrapolated to the curve(be the curve). So, for example, your first code is absolutely perfect as it is for the first `data` except that you got the "change line" from a region (which resulting to be the change at x around 42) rather than a single point, like at 40, but I think that is easily fixable. The other issue with your code is that for some reason is not working with `data1` correctly. So, is only needed to modify it to get "change line" at a x value and to work with `data1`